# Lie group structure of incompressible deformations?

Tags: lie-groups, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

In the context of incompressible elasticity, I failed at finding
a Lie group structure, which respects the incopressibility.

**Question:**

Let $\mathcal B, \mathcal S$ be Riemannian manifolds and $\overline{\mathcal B}$ is compact.

Does the smooth manifold of incompressible deformations
$$
\mathcal{C} := \{ \varphi: \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal S \mid \varphi \in \mathrm{Diff}(\mathcal B, \mathcal S) ~\text{with}~ \mathrm{det}(\mathrm{D} \varphi) = 1\}
$$
admit a Lie group structure?
(Here, $\mathcal B$ is the reference configuration of the body (fixed in time) and $\mathcal S$ is the space in which the body is placed, i.e. $\varphi(X)$ is the current position of the material point $X$.)

Is a Lie structure only possible, if for example $\mathcal S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ or if $\mathcal S$ is a Lie group?

Recommendations for related literature or a short 'No, there is no Lie group' are very welcome!

**My problem:**

A reasonable candidate for the Lie group operation is the composition of maps. 
But if $\mathcal B \neq \mathcal S$, it is tricky to define $\varphi_2 \circ \varphi_1$ for $\varphi_i \in \mathrm{Diff}(\mathcal B, \mathcal S)$.

*Fluid dynamics:*

In fluid dynamics, there seem to exists a Lie group, since typically the Eulerian perspective is used. If $\Omega$ denotes the domain of the fluid,
then the displacement of fluid particles is a map $\phi \in \mathrm{Diff}(\Omega, \Omega)$, which is a Lie group with the composition of two maps as group operation.

But I was not able to transfer this to the setting above.

Comment: Well, for a 2d manifold, the group is just that of [Poisson brackets, namely $SU(\infty)$](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/9tahoe.pdf), as you are probably aware from 2d hydrodynamics. In fact, as you can tell from Liouville's theorem in classical mechanics, classical phase-space flows in all dimensions are incompressible. In odd-dimensional manifolds, Nambu brackets are utilized, and the group structure is more moot.

Comment: A modern [book on symplectomorphism groups, 2018](https://www.amazon.com/Fluid-Mechanics-Geometrical-Point-View/dp/0198805020). For the standard theory, see [JMP 1990](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.528788).